# simplifying expression of roots of cubic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

I came across with this question about roots of polynomials.

Suppose $a$, $b$ and $c$ are the roots of $x^3-4x+1=0$. Find the value of $ \frac{a^2bc}{a^3+1}+\frac{ab^2c}{b^3+1}+\frac{abc^2}{c^3+1}. $

I tried combining the fractions but only yields an expression that cannot be expressed in terms of Vieta's formulas or maybe I may have overlooked on to something. Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

Clearly, $abc=-1\ne0$

As $a$ satisfies  $x^3-4x+1=0, a^3+1=4a\implies\dfrac{a^2bc}{a^3+1}=\dfrac{a^2bc}{4a}=\dfrac{abc}4$ as $a\ne0$